# tic tac toe program on python presenting some kind of error poping a black screen with no response of the program

Tags: python, pygame, screen

okay so i am trying to build a pvp x o programm but everytime i launch the program a black pygame screen appears and the program fail to run , please can anyone explain to where is the problem and how should i make up to it?

```
import os
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*

pygame.init()

ev = pygame.event.get()
x=0
y=0


window=pygame.display.set_mode((700,700))
background=pygame.image.load('blanc.png')
grille=pygame.image.load('Tic-tac-toe.png')

window.blit(background,(0,0))
window.blit(grille,(50,50))

x=pygame.image.load("X-400.png")

o=pygame.image.load("o.png")

GRID=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
tour=1

a=tour/2



while tour<10:
 for event in ev:
  while jouer==true:
   if a==int(a):
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTON and event.button==3:
     pygame.mouse.get_pos(x,y)
     if x<189:

        if y<192:
            window.blit(o,(50,50))
            GRID[1]=2
        elif 275<y<382:
            window.blit(o,(50,275))
            GRID[4]=2
        elif y>468:
            window.blit(o,(50,468))
            GRID[7]=2
    elif 275<x<377:
         if  y<192:
            window.blit(o,(275,50))
            GRID[2]=2
         elif 275<y<382:
            window.blit(o,(275,275))
            GRID[5]=2
         elif y>468:
            window.blit(o,(275,468))
            GRID[8]=2
    elif x>461:
         if  y<192:
           window.blit(o,(461,50))
           GRID[3]=2
         elif 275<y<382:
            window.blit(o,(461,275))
            GRID[6]=2
         elif y>468:
            window.blit(o,(461,468))
            GRID[9]=2
    tour=tour+1
   elif a!=int(a):
    if event.type== MOUSEBUTONDOWN and event.button== 1:
     pygame.mouse.get_pos(x,y)
     if x<189:

        if y<192 and GRID[1]==0:
            window.blit(X-400,(50,50))
            GRID[1]=1
        elif 275<y<382:
            window.blit(X-400,(50,275))
            GRID[4]=1
        elif y>468:
            window.blit(X-400,(50,468))
            GRID[7]=1
     elif 275<x<377:
         if  y<192:
            window.blit(X-400,(275,50))
            GRID[2]=1
         elif 275<y<382:
            window.blit(X-400,(275,275))
            GRID[5]=1
         elif y>468:
            window.blit(X-400,(275,468))
            GRID[8]=1
     elif x>461:
         if  y<192:
           window.blit(X-400,(461,50))
           GRID[3]=1
         elif 275<y<382:
            window.blit(X-400,(461,275))
            GRID[6]=1
         elif y>468:
            window.blit(X-400,(461,468))
            GRID[9]=1
   tour=tour+1

pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: There are quite a lot of things that need to be changed. The biggest problem is the inner `while jouer` loop in your event loop, which should be removed because it blocks the event loop. The event loop also can't work because you have to call `pygame.event.get()` for each iteration of the while loop, so change it to `for event in pygame.event.get():`. The next problem is that you use the name `x` for the position variable and the image variable (the second assignment overrides the first). There's also no event type `MOUSEBUTTON`.

Comment: `pygame.display.flip()` has to be in the while loop, so that the screen can be updated every frame.

Comment: hey thanks everything is all right but i don t know how to correct mousebutton i saw it on a tutorial do you know how

Comment: There are the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, `MOUSEBUTTONUP` and `MOUSEMOTION` event types.

Comment: okay all good is 'pygame.mouse.get_pos(x,y)' a correct syntax for x and y being the coordinates of the mouse click??

Comment: Try `x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`.

Comment: look i put as an answer my modified algorithme it is not pasting images

Answer (score 1):

now i just don t understand how there image when i click

```
import os
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import*

    pygame.init()

    ev = pygame.event.get()




window=pygame.display.set_mode((700,700))
background=pygame.image.load('blanc.png')
grille=pygame.image.load('Tic-tac-toe.png')

window.blit(background,(0,0))
window.blit(grille,(50,50))

XX=pygame.image.load("X-400.png")

o=pygame.image.load("o.png")

GRID=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
tour=1

a=tour/2



while tour<10:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
   if a==int(a):
    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button==3:
     pygame.mouse.get_pos(x,y)
     if x<189:

        if y<192:
            window.blit(o,(50,50))
            GRID[1]=2
        elif 275<y<382:
            window.blit(o,(50,275))
            GRID[4]=2
        elif y>468:
            window.blit(o,(50,468))
            GRID[7]=2
    elif 275<x<377:
         if  y<192:
            window.blit(o,(275,50))
            GRID[2]=2
        elif 275<y<382:
            window.blit(o,(275,275))
            GRID[5]=2
        elif y>468:
            window.blit(o,(275,468))
            GRID[8]=2
    elif x>461:
         if  y<192:
           window.blit(o,(461,50))
           GRID[3]=2
         elif 275<y<382:
            window.blit(o,(461,275))
            GRID[6]=2
         elif y>468:
            window.blit(o,(461,468))
            GRID[9]=2
    pygame.display.flip()
    tour=tour+1
   elif a!=int(a):
    if event.type== MOUSEBUTONDOWN and event.button== 1:
     pygame.mouse.get_pos(x,y)
     if x<189:

         if y<192 and GRID[1]==0:
            window.blit(XX,(50,50))
            GRID[1]=1
        elif 275<y<382:
            window.blit(XX,(50,275))
            GRID[4]=1
        elif y>468:
            window.blit(XX,(50,468))
            GRID[7]=1
     elif 275<x<377:
         if  y<192:
            window.blit(XX,(275,50))
            GRID[2]=1
         elif 275<y<382:
            window.blit(XX,(275,275))
            GRID[5]=1
         elif y>468:
            window.blit(XX,(275,468))
            GRID[8]=1
     elif x>461:
         if  y<192:
           window.blit(XX,(461,50))
           GRID[3]=1
         elif 275<y<382:
            window.blit(XX,(461,275))
            GRID[6]=1
         elif y>468:
            window.blit(XX,(461,468))
            GRID[9]=1
   pygame.display.flip()
   tour=tour+1


fps=15
```

Comment: The `while tour<10:` loop stops when the tour variable is 10 and you add 1 to it every frame, so it stops after 10 iterations. Actually, you should use the `while jouer:` condition for this outer while loop or alternatively increment the `tour` variable only if a mouse button gets pressed.

Comment: it is still not pasting the first image :(

Comment: or more exactly the page is not responding

Comment: Yes, there are still more issues, especially with the event loop. I'm not sure which one we should fix next. ;)

Comment: okay thanks alot i couldn t have arrived to this point without you if you have any thoughts feel free to share them with me king

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer but just the next step towards a working game. I've introduced a `player` variable which can be 0 or 1 for the first or second player. Then in the event loop I set the current `image` to `XX` `if player == 0:`, otherwise to `o`. And at the end of the loop (if the mouse button was pressed) I increment the `player` and then use modulo 2 `%= 2` so that it cycles between 0 and 1. As you see it still doesn't work correctly, but it's an improvement. ;)

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,700))
window.fill((30, 40, 50))

XX = pygame.Surface((90, 90), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.line(XX, (60, 100, 200), (0, 0), (90, 90), 3)
pygame.draw.line(XX, (60, 100, 200), (90, 0), (0, 90), 3)

o = pygame.Surface((90, 90), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(o, (90, 200, 50), (45, 45), 45, 3)

GRID = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

player = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
jouer = True

while jouer:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            jouer = False
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if player == 0:
                image = XX
            else:
                image = o
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if x<189:
                if y<192:
                    window.blit(image,(50,50))
                    GRID[1] = 2
                elif 275<y<382:
                    window.blit(image,(50,275))
                    GRID[4] = 2
                elif y>468:
                    window.blit(image,(50,468))
                    GRID[7] = 2
            elif 275<x<377:
                if y<192:
                    window.blit(image,(275,50))
                    GRID[2] = 2
                elif 275<y<382: 
                    window.blit(image,(275,275))
                    GRID[5] = 2
                elif y>468:
                    window.blit(image,(275,468))
                    GRID[8] = 2
            elif x>461:
                 if  y<192:
                   window.blit(image,(461,50))
                   GRID[3] = 2
                 elif 275<y<382:
                    window.blit(image,(461,275))
                    GRID[6] = 2
                 elif y>468:
                    window.blit(image,(461,468))
                    GRID[9] = 2
            player += 1
            player %= 2

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: I've replaced the images, so that I could test the code.

Comment: you come from god i am finishing everything i ll post it when it s done thx king

Comment: hi ksrx sorry for bothering need your bhelp one last time our pvp is working but we are trying to put some kind oh screen to play again or something can you see where is the problem?? i ll put the new as an answer there is no prob if you can t help we re worcking on it

Comment: I'll take a look at your code but better post a new question. BTW, if you liked this answer you can upvote and also accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,700))
window.fill((25, 25, 25))
grille=pygame.image.load('Tic-tac-toe.png')
window.blit(grille,(50,50))
XX = pygame.Surface((150, 150), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.line(XX, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0), (150,150), 5)
pygame.draw.line(XX, (255, 255, 255), (150, 0), (0, 150), 5)

o = pygame.Surface((150, 150), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(o, (255, 255 , 0), (75, 75), 75, 5)
def pvploop():
    GRID = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    gagner =True
    player = 0
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    jouer = True
    value=1
    while jouer and not gagner:
        gameDisplay.fill(25,25,25)
        message_to_screen("Game over, press C to play again or Q to quit",)
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            jouer = False
         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                 if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                  jouer = False
                 if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                   pvploop()   




    while jouer and gagner:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               jouer = False
           elif GRID[0]==2 and GRID[1]==2 and GRID[2]==2:
               print('O a gagne')
               gagner =False

           elif GRID[3]==2 and GRID[4]==2 and GRID[5]==2:
              print('O a gagne')
           elif GRID[6]==2 and GRID[7]==2 and GRID[8]==2:
              print('O a gagne')
           elif GRID[0]==2 and GRID[3]==2 and GRID[6]==2:
             print('O a gagne')
           elif GRID[1]==2 and GRID[4]==2 and GRID[7]==2:
             print('O a gagne')
           elif GRID[2]==2 and GRID[5]==2 and GRID[8]==2:
             print('O a gagne')
           elif GRID[0]==2 and GRID[4]==2 and GRID[8]==2:
                 print('O a gagne')
           elif GRID[2]==2 and GRID[4]==2 and GRID[6]==2:
                print('O a gagne')
           elif GRID[0]==2 and GRID[3]==2 and GRID[6]==2:
                     print('O a gagne')



           elif GRID[0]==1 and GRID[1]==1 and GRID[2]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[3]==1 and GRID[4]==1 and GRID[0]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[6]==1 and GRID[7]==1 and GRID[8]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[0]==1 and GRID[1]==1 and GRID[2]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[3]==1 and GRID[4]==1 and GRID[5]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[6]==1 and GRID[7]==1 and GRID[8]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[0]==1 and GRID[3]==1 and GRID[6]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[1]==1 and GRID[4]==1 and GRID[7]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[2]==1 and GRID[5]==1 and GRID[8]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[3]==1 and GRID[6]==1 and GRID[0]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[4]==1 and GRID[7]==1 and GRID[1]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[5]==1 and GRID[8]==1 and GRID[2]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[0]==1 and GRID[4]==1 and GRID[8]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[2]==1 and GRID[4]==1 and GRID[6]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[4]==1 and GRID[8]==1 and GRID[0]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')
           elif GRID[4]==1 and GRID[6]==1 and GRID[2]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')

           elif GRID[0]==1 and GRID[8]==1 and GRID[4]==1:
                   print (' X a gagne')

           elif GRID[2]==1 and GRID[6]==1 and GRID[4]==1:
                   print (' X a gagne')

            elif GRID[0]==1 and GRID[1]==1 and GRID[2]==1:
                     print (' X a gagne')

           elif GRID[3]==1 and GRID[4]==1 and GRID[5]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')

           elif GRID[6]==1 and GRID[7]==1 and GRID[8]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')

           elif GRID[0]==1 and GRID[3]==1 and GRID[6]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')

           elif GRID[1]==1 and GRID[4]==1 and GRID[7]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')

           elif GRID[2]==1 and GRID[5]==1 and GRID[8]==1:
                    print (' X a gagne')




           elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
               if player == 0:
                   image = XX
               else:
                   image = o
               x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                   if x<232:
                   if y<234 and GRID[0] == 0 :
                       window.blit(image,(75,75))
                       player += 1
                       GRID[0] = value
                   elif 234<y<425 and GRID[3]==0:
                       window.blit(image,(75,275))
                       player += 1
                       GRID[3] = value
                   elif y>425 and GRID[6] == 0 :
                       window.blit(image,(75,468))
                       player += 1
                       GRID[6] = value
               elif 232<x<419:
                   if y<234 and GRID[1] == 0 :
                       window.blit(image,(275,75))
                       player += 1
                       GRID[1] = value
                   elif 234<y<425 and GRID[4] == 0 :
                       window.blit(image,(275,275))
                       player += 1
                       GRID[4] = value
                   elif y>425 and GRID[7] == 0 :
                       window.blit(image,(275,468))
                       player += 1
                       GRID[7] = value
               elif x>419:
                    if  y<234 and GRID[2] == 0 :
                      window.blit(image,(465,75))
                      player += 1
                      GRID[2] = value
                    elif 234<y<425 and GRID[5]==0:
                       window.blit(image,(465,275))
                       player += 1
                       GRID[5] = value
                    elif y>425 and GRID[8] == 0 :
                       window.blit(image,(465,468))
                       player += 1
                       GRID[8] = value
               player %= 2
               value=player+1
               print GRID
     pygame.display.flip()
     clock.tick(30)

    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Hey, it would be better to post this as a new question, but try to polish your code first and turn it into a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Especially the indentation of your code blocks should be fixed to make your code more readable (they should be indented by 4 spaces). And make sure that we can just copy the code and run it. Also, show us and explain what you've tried to implement the different scenes.